# Apigee - Java callout, Resource

Tags: apigee

Apigee java callout:
To execute java callout, I uploaded .jar file at org level in apigee. I made reference of the jar (and Execution class) in java-callout policy, but I get error during deployment of proxy - "Could not extract the java resource". Using curl command I verified that jar is loaded as java type, and name of resource is correct.

curl command used to upload the jar.
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"  -X POST -d@{JARfileName.jar} http://{HOST}/v1/organizations/{ORG}/resourcefiles?"name={JARfileName.jar}&type=java"

Any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the [documentation page](http://apigee.com/docs/ja/api-services/content/customize-api-using-java) for `JavaCallout`s, this feature is only available on paid-for Apigee orgs. If you're a paying customer I'd suggest contacting Apigee Support directly to get help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I further investigated, it has to do with java class loader - in built(fixed) java class loader sequence is to look for dependencies in proxy-level to Apigee platform level, not in other-direction. Example - you can not reference entry class from jar uploaded at platform level and look for its dependencies at proxy level. Anyway a work-around solution works for me.

Suggestion to Apigee team -
It would be helpful if there is way to define location of dependent jars in Api-proxy(explicit jar location in java callout), this way one can explicitly manage how dependent jar/class is being referenced. And also, will be able to upload common/shared class at platform level and bundle proxy specific configuration at Proxy-level.

Regards,
Kamesh